# why does my count value stay 0?

Tags: python

I have struggled for hte past hour trying to figure out why my "count" variable stays 0 when I run this code.

```
def main():

print "There are %s Instagram Routes in the DB" % db.routes.count()

results = defaultdict(dict)
d= 1.5 #distance
t= 4*3600 #in seconds
# For each route a_route in db.routes
print "Start of for each route for loop"
all_routes = db.routes.find().limit(5)


for a_route in all_routes:
    print "restart"


    # for a set of size 1 to N:
    for i in range(1,a_route['n_points']+1):

        # Create set of size n 
        set_of_size_i_pts = select_points(a_route,i)


        # Calcalute the number of possible routes for the set 
        x_route = find_routes(set_of_size_i_pts,t,d)
        x_length = len(set_of_size_i_pts)
        results[a_route['_id']].update({x_length:x_route})

print results

def select_points(a_route,i):
    pts = a_route['points']
    return random.sample(pts,i)

def find_routes(set_of_size_i_pts,t,d):
    all_routes = db.routes.find().limit(5)

    count = 0
    for a_route in all_routes:
        if is_legitimate_route(set_of_size_i_pts,a_route,t,d):
              print "hel"
              count+=1
              print "count: %s" % count
        b = 6
        print b
    return count
```

Output:

```
r

estart
hel
count: 1
6
hel
count: 1
6
hel
count: 1
6
hel
count: 1
6
hel
....
```

Any advice would be really appreciated!

Thank you
The goal is to be able to count the number of true statements. This is why I increment by 1 each time.

Comment: What is `is_legitimate_route` doing? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Is this the actual code? Because I am not sure where is this `1` being printed after each `hel`?

Comment: Along with the previous point, why is 7 not being printed?

Comment: When I minimize code without specific functions like `s_legitimate_route` and so on its work well and function returned incremented `count`

Comment: Hi-- I've updated the code to include more of the script

Comment: @AspiringSoftwareDeveloper: Please correct the indentation as well. It is hard to understand otherwise.

Comment: Looks like there are only one increment happend in loop. Maybe it's because there are only one element in `all_routes` collection is_legitimate_route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this for loop 'for a_route in all_routes:' is executing only once whenever it is called from here 'x_route = find_routes(set_of_size_i_pts,t,d)'.

Check this in your code. And run it again. Also try the below code, See if that prints incremented count values or not. I have added a static number in for loop just to confirm that if your for loop executes more than one time then it will must print incremented count.

```
def main():

print "There are %s Instagram Routes in the DB" % db.routes.count()

results = defaultdict(dict)
d= 1.5 #distance
t= 4*3600 #in seconds
# For each route a_route in db.routes
print "Start of for each route for loop"
all_routes = db.routes.find().limit(5)


for a_route in all_routes:
    print "restart"


    # for a set of size 1 to N:
    for i in range(1,a_route['n_points']+1):

        # Create set of size n 
        set_of_size_i_pts = select_points(a_route,i)


        # Calcalute the number of possible routes for the set 
        x_route = find_routes(set_of_size_i_pts,t,d)
        x_length = len(set_of_size_i_pts)
        results[a_route['_id']].update({x_length:x_route})

print results

def select_points(a_route,i):
    pts = a_route['points']
    return random.sample(pts,i)

def find_routes(set_of_size_i_pts,t,d):
    all_routes = db.routes.find().limit(5)

    count = 0
    for a_route in range(1, 10):

        print "hel"
        count+=1
        print "count: %s" % count
        b = 6
        print b
    return count
```

Comment: Thanks!  Basically: it was only evaluating to True 1x